# Having two connections with different IP blocks (One is Global Protect VPN)

Tags: networking, vpn

I have a wifi connection on a windows 10 Machine. It has the following conf

**DEFAULT LOCAL SETTINGS**

```
IP: 162.168.0.10 
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0 
Default GW: 192.168.0.1
```

When I connected to a VPN using Global Protect it creates a second network connection within a 10.x block

**VPN CONNECTION TO 10.x network**

```
IP: 10.170.170.10
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.255
Default Gateway: EMPTY
```

The problem is when I connected to VPN I no longer can access internet even if the wifi connection is active. I only can access to VPN network.

The strange thing is when I connected to another VPN network having a 192.x IP block. Everthing runs perfect. No access problem.

**VPN CONNECTION TO 192.x network**

```
IP: 192.168.128.102
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.255
Default Gateway: EMPTY
```

I think there is a conflict because of the different IP blocks. Any ideas to solve are welcome

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a feature called split tunneling ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_tunneling ) of some VPN software.
The example described in the wikipedia page:

> For example, suppose a user utilizes a remote access VPN software
>   client connecting to a corporate network using a hotel wireless
>   network. The user with split tunneling enabled is able to connect to
>   file servers, database servers, mail servers and other servers on the 
>   corporate network through the VPN connection. When the user connects
>   to Internet resources (Web sites, FTP sites, etc.), the connection
>   request goes directly out the gateway provided by the hotel network.

The configuration of this feature (if implemented) dependr from the VPN software that you are using. Try to search on google "< yuor_vpn_software > split tunnel".